# How to add a title bar in Android while sorting?

Tags: android, sorting, spinner

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner spin;
    TextView tex;
    String[] country = {"A", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Etc"};// A to Z country names
    String[] code = {"+93", "+91", "Etc"}; // A to Z country Code

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        tex = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tex);

        ArrayAdapter aa1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
        aa1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setPrompt("Select the Country");
        spin.setAdapter(aa1);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                tex.setText(code[arg2]);
                // tex.setText(country[arg2]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want to display the country's list in alphabetic order on spinner. And before that it should display the A, B, C up to Z. But This A to Z must be unselectable mode in spinner list. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your custom adapter that extends the ArrayAdapter.

it will probably be very easy, something like:

```
 // the get view on your adapter
getView(LayoutInflater, etc, etc){
   convertView = super.getView(inflater, etc, etc);
   if(getItem(position).equals("A") || getItem(position).equals("B") || // etc, or create some clever way to go through a ArrayList with just the letters ){
      convertView. // set not clickable stuff
     }
}
```

but I reckon the Spinner still will close the list whenever the user clicks. Maybe you must override the spinner OnItemClick to get a coherent behaviour.

Comment: just Google `Android custom arrayadapter` and you can find several tutorials on how to build a custom adapter, and after you understand that part, come back to here and re-read this answer I gave ;)